# what is the best way to include svg's in your site (speed wise)

Tags: html, svg, pagespeed

I was getting in depth in web development, and I was thinking about speed. So I have learned that the less files a browser has to request from the server the better, but the other thing to keep in mind is the file size so comes the question, is it better to include vector images as `svg` tags which will reduce the number of files requested, but increase the size of the html file. Assuming the svg has a noticeable size.

Comment: [Recommended reading](https://svgontheweb.com/)

Comment: I'm not seeing an on-topic question here. The "best" way will always depend on the SVGs' content, size, placement, etc.. There are no silver bullets in performance; you have to do the work of measuring and deciding amongst the tradeoffs.

Answer (score 0):

combine multiple images in a single img file and position it using css background.

Example: use next, prev, up and down images in same image seperated by equal space, and position it by x axis and y axis using css background property.

Comment: This is definitely one way to do it, but if the images are large, you are slowing the page load down, not speeding it up. In that case, having multiple images to download in parallel would be faster than a single massive image.

Comment: there is a thing called WebP. WebP lossless images are 26% smaller in size compared to PNGs - according to google

Comment: That should have been part of your answer, then. And there's a lot of other ways to accomplish the same thing, so again, this is one way to do it, but not necessarily "the best".

Comment: I don't recommend using this way. Background images are harder to optimize, harder to lazy-load.